# How comes my script fails to run while executed by a trigger but is successful when executed manually?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm not sure if I have encountered with a bug or is just me not fully understanding how triggers work, probably the second one :D.

I have a google apps script that collects information through a series of requests to our CRM's API and puts it on a Google Docs Spreadsheet, the script takes a while to run, however, it runs successfully (I run it manually every morning, takes about 3 minutes). But when I try to automate that task, I get an error message saying my script exceeded its execution time limit.

I tried setting up my triggers manually, creating them within the script, breaking down my script reducing the number of API requests (taking less then a minute to execute) and execute it several times so I get the whole information. Every single time I get the same error message.

Am I missing something here? Any help will be much appreciated!

Edit: The mail I received has this error message: "Exceeded maximum execution time".

Edit2: I was able to fix this (party). I came across the answer for this question [Exceeded maximum execution time in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854573/)  and worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

There are some limits to Google Apps Scripts that you must keep in mind: see [Quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas).

It is possible that you are exceeding your total runtime for Triggers. There is also the shorter *individual* execution time limits on Triggers. I think I remember reading somewhere that Triggers have a lower total execution time limit per execution, but I can't remember where I saw it, and I can't find a source, even in Google's documentation.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585536/google-apps-script-triggers-your-quota-of-triggers-has-been-exceeded) is also similar...

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say it's a bug, however as my own painfully experience, I can tell it's not the same running the script manually than through a time-driven trigger.
Sometimes it's just slower, but others it fails for timeout.

I don't know your specifics (there is no code available), but I would recommend you to use a retry exponential backoff function wrapping any critical call and also check for a timeout warning (let's say at 5 minutes) within the main loop.

Comment: Hi Fausto, thank you for your response. Could you explain me a little more this exponential backoff function wrapping approach?